# matplotlib: change individual cell dimensions in heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am building a heatmap using Matplotlib, but I would like for every cell to have its own dimension based on other info I have. This is how I am currently building the heatmap:

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.pcolor(data.T,cmap=plt.cm.Reds,edgecolors='k')
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 50) + 0.5)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 50) + 0.5)
ax.set_xticklabels(keys,minor=False,fontsize=7)
ax.set_yticklabels(keys,minor=False,fontsize=10)
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

which produces a nice heatmap but with all cells having the same dimensions, which I would like to change (individually). Thanks for any help(:

Comment: Look into PatchCollection.